# Method to sort alpha after removing duplicates java (collections)

Tags: java, sorting, collections, alpha

Working with collections and arraylists in java and writing a method to take user input (list) and put it into a method that removes the duplicates and then sorts the list alphabetically to print. The method I have written successfully removes duplicates, but will not sort alphabetically. Here is my method body:

```
public static void sortNoDups(ArrayList<String> list) {
        // e
        ArrayList<String> printedList = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("\nWithout duplicates, sorted alphabetically:");
        for (String i : list) {
            if (!printedList.contains(i)) {
                printedList.add(i);
                Collections.sort(printedList);
                System.out.print(i + " ");

            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I have also tried it without the line "Collections.sort(printedList)", and with "Collections.sort(list)" to no avail. Happy to include additional code from above if needed, but felt I should start specific to see if there are any glaring errors I'm just missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine – it is correctly sorting `printedList` – but you aren't actually printing that out. Right now, your code is iterating through the original `list`. The thing you are printing is `System.out.print(i + " ");` which is just printing the next string from `list`.

To print the contents of the sorted `printedList`, add this to the end of your method:

```
for (String s : printedList) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Also, you might want to move `Collections.sort(printedList)` to the end of the method as well. That way, you'll call `sort` one time at the end, instead of calling it each time in your `for` loop.